# How to get response of triggered github action workflow using python script?

Tags: python, github-actions, cicd

I have written a python script (which was the main requirement) to trigger the github action using workflow_dispatch event. Referred github api link: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event

Workflow triggered as intended. But i am not able to get the workflow success or failure status using python code. Can someone please help me in getting the workflow status code using python script?

I have tried to print the response for the workflow_dispatch event, but i got only for triggered or not triggered. I need Success/Failure status.

Comment: Please include your Python script in your question. Thanks!